# Using SQL Keywords in C# MySqlCommand.CommandText

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax

I'm moving my stored procedures to C# code.
In the stored procedures I have something like

```
Begin
SET @Id = null;
IF ?Status = 0 THEN SET ? ?DateToday = UTC_TIMESTAMP(); END IF;
SELECT * FROM TABLE
END
```

In the C# Code I just copy pasted everything inside Begin and END. Like so,

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.CommandText = @"SET @Id = null;
IF ?Status = 0 THEN SET ? ?DateToday = UTC_TIMESTAMP(); END IF;
SELECT * FROM TABLE"
```

I have an error in the If statement saying incorrect syntax. The stored procedure is working but not when I place it in C# code.

Comment: Why not use only command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"

Comment: Does your stored procedure have parameters?

Comment: @Damith its just an example, the Set and If statement are causing errors.

Comment: @BlackFrog yes it does. i've set it in the code too.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the logic of Stored Procedures. As its name implies stored procedures are functions that are stored in the database itself. And you can invoke them by calling their names.

Hence you cannot just put the stored procedure function code in your C# code, I mean you shouldn't.

**Update:**
If you only want to use T-SQL statements (`if-else` blocks and so) check out this [link](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp2010/adonet/Lesson05.htm).

Comment: I understand, but what is the counterpart of Set and the If statement in C# CommandText?btw thanks for you reply :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a stored procedure then you can call it using a stored procedure syntax like this;

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(someconnectionstring)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myStoredProc", con)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      //If you have parameters in your SP, add like this else ignore below line
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@myparam", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = somevalue;

      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Cosytyle;- Any specific reason to do that. As it is not a good coding practice?